# How to get nginx to set Server header to that of the upstream?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a very specific `Server:` header set upstream, however, when Nginx is a reverse proxy, it sets its own Server header . The `Server` header is set to `Server: nginx/1.23.1`, for example. The the upstream server header is dynamic and can change every request (ex: `Server: gunicorn/19.4.5` or `Server: gunicorn/20.0.4`). Is there a way to pass the upstream's `Server` header to nginx so that it is set how the upstream sent it? I know there is `more_set_headers` but that sets the headers to a static value. I need them to be dynamic specifically, based on how the upstream `proxy_pass` is setting them.

sample config:

```
http {
    log_format custom '{"http_ssl_ja3": "$http_ssl_ja3", "http_ssl_ja3_hash": "$http_ssl_ja3_hash", "remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "request": "$request"}';
    server {
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
        proxy_buffers 4 512k;
        proxy_buffer_size 256k
        listen                 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl;
        ssl_protocols          TLSv1.3 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_dhparam            /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
        ssl_ciphers            'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
        access_log             /dev/stdout custom;
        ssl_certificate_key    "redacted";
        ssl_certificate        "redacted";
        location = / {
            proxy_pass             http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You can pass through specific headers by specifying `proxy_pass_header Server;`. The correct headers are now being proxied.